# AngularJS extra data in request

Tags: json, angularjs, post

I'm trying to create a function which sends data from a form to the server. The server then sends back the id of the created entry. This id then should get sent to the server with data from another field group. I've done something similar with jQuery, but in this case I wasn't able to push the id as extra information to "data2".

It shows the error "data2.push() is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.createNew = function() {
        var data = $scope.fields1;
        var data2 = $scope.fields2;

        $http.post("myurl", data)
             .success(function(response) {
                  data2.push('rid' , response.id[0]); <------- add the id from the response for the second request
                  $http.post("myurl2", data2)
                       .then(function(data) {
                          $location.url('/entry/' + response.id[0]);
                  });
        });
}
```

Comment: I'd say `data2` is not an array. You tell us what `$scope.fields2` is :)

Comment: Hi trombonist,
Try Replacing data2.push('rid' , response.id[0]); 

With

data2['rid']= response.id[0];

Comment: fields2 is the second part of the form, that is sent to a different url than the first part.

data2['rid']= response.id[0]; worked. thank you very much :)